# Is there any way to ensure that duplicate records are not inserted in kafka topic?

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-producer-api

I have been trying to implement a queuing mechanism using kafka where I want to ensure that duplicate records are not inserted into topic created.

I found that iteration is possible in consumer. Is there any way by which we can do this in producer thread as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is known as exactly-once processing.

You might be interested in the first part of [Kafka FAQ](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/FAQ#FAQ-HowdoIgetexactly-oncemessagingfromKafka?) that describes some approaches on how to avoid duplication on data production (i.e. on producer side):

> Exactly once semantics has two parts: avoiding duplication during data
>   production and avoiding duplicates during data consumption.
>
> **There are two approaches to getting exactly once semantics during data
>   production:**
>
> 1. Use a single-writer per partition and every time you get a network
>      error check the last message in that partition to see if your last
>      write succeeded
> 2. Include a primary key (UUID or something) in the
>      message and deduplicate on the consumer.
>
> If you do one of these things, the log that Kafka hosts will be
>   duplicate-free. However, reading without duplicates depends on some
>   co-operation from the consumer too. If the consumer is periodically
>   checkpointing its position then if it fails and restarts it will
>   restart from the checkpointed position. Thus if the data output and
>   the checkpoint are not written atomically it will be possible to get
>   duplicates here as well. This problem is particular to your storage
>   system. For example, if you are using a database you could commit
>   these together in a transaction. The HDFS loader Camus that LinkedIn
>   wrote does something like this for Hadoop loads. The other alternative
>   that doesn't require a transaction is to store the offset with the
>   data loaded and deduplicate using the topic/partition/offset
>   combination.
>
> I think there are two improvements that would make this a lot easier:
>
> 1. Producer idempotence could be done automatically and much more cheaply
>      by optionally integrating support for this on the server.
> 2. The existing
>      high-level consumer doesn't expose a lot of the more fine grained
>      control of offsets (e.g. to reset your position). We will be working
>      on that soon

Comment: Can we maintain uniqueness by using unique keys while adding records in a topic?

Comment: @ShubhangiGupta It depends. Do you consider two messages with `key=1,value=a` and `key=2,value=a` as distinct or as duplicates?

Comment: I consider this as distinct value in a similar way as a hashmap.

Comment: Since you consider these key-value pairs as distinct, then by providing unique keys you will end up with unique records. But it will be much more useful if you provide an example because I am still not sure what are you trying to achieve.

Comment: For instance, I want to store records in topics created as follows: If one record with key=1 is already present in the topic and if I want to insert another record with key=1 in this topic again, then it should not be inserted or the older value should be updated as it happens in a hashmap.